# sqlalchemy Session object has no attribute add

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to insert the data to mysql server, While doing so when i try to add the data into the SQLalchemy sesion i am getting the error "Generator object has no attribute add"

```
db=get_db()
temp = schema.User(**filtered_dict)
insert_data=models.User(**temp.dict())
db = get_db()
db.add(insert_data)
db.commit()
db.refresh()
```

Session generator:

```
def get_db():
 
    db_session = sessionlocal()
    try:
        yield db_session
    finally:
        db_session.close()
```

session creation

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:password@localhost:3305/line_api"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
)
sessionlocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


Base = declarative_base()
```

please help...

Comment: @IljaEverilä i hopeits t=not the issue with the generator, Only issue is that my object "sessionlocal " has no attribute add

Comment: You do not call the `get_db` function directly, you usually use FastAPIs `Depends()` construct to insert it where it is required: `def foo(db: SessionLocal = Depends(get_db)):` - this will then be populated when the `foo` endpoint gets called. This is the reason for `yield`-ing the session, since it allows FastAPI to handle the dependency and clean it up when it is no longer in use. However, to do that, you have to use FastAPIs dependency injection methods and not call the method directly.

Answer (score 6):

###### Simple Solution

I ran into a similar issue in my own FastAPI project with SQLAlchemy. The issue stems from the gathering of the db session from a `yield` keyword. `yield` returns a generator rather than returning the sqlalchemy db session as you're expecting. You can read more about the yield expression here:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr

To fix the code you need to call the internal `__next__` function in some form on the `generator` object returned from `get_db`. You can do this a variety of ways (some may be more stylistically accurate than my suggestion).

```py
temp = schema.User(**filtered_dict)
insert_data=models.User(**temp.dict())
db_gen = get_db()
db = next(db_gen)
db.add(insert_data)
db.commit()
db.refresh()
```

EDIT with var reference to generator Thanks to @DustinMichels in the comments.

Adding the `next` function call should fix the issue.

---

###### Using Async Generators

Since we are not prepending the function `get_db` with `async` we get a normal generator. However, if we add `async` to this function definition, we can no longer use `__next__` as a solution. Making the function asynchronous would also help making sure connections are closed correctly (see comments).

If a developer decides to add the `async` keyword then you have a couple options:

FastAPI's `Depends` system does work perfectly with asynchronous generators and can call the function for you, populating a nice parameter with your connection.

Alternatively, you can call `asend(None)` on an asynchronous generator to get the first value of the asynchronous generator. (There are also better ways to do this as well like using an async for loop or `__anext__` function call). More to read here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#implementation-details

```py
async def get_db():
    db_session = sessionlocal()
    try:
        yield db_session
    finally:
        db_session.close()

# ...

temp = schema.User(**filtered_dict)
insert_data=models.User(**temp.dict())
db = get_db().asend(None)
db.add(insert_data)
db.commit()
db.refresh()
```

Comment: @RandallShanePhD Is there a component of the question I didn't answer? I can edit it into the explanation.

Comment: Appreciate the callout @TFlexSoom - that's a solid answer!

Comment: I am feeling confused about the same bit of code. When will the `finally` block be executed, and close the db connection?

Comment: @DustinMichels, Thank you for the comment. That is a very good point that I will try to add in to the answer. From personal testing, it seems that the finally comes into play whenever the reference to the generator can be deleted. This does mean that it could trigger early with the way the code is currently written. I found that setting `get_db()` to a variable does help avoid closing the connection.

Personally, I would recommend making the function async. This is what I did in my own implementation, and it works well when injected into the FastAPI dependency system.

Comment: Personal Testing Script if anyone is interested from the comment above.
https://gist.github.com/TFlexSoom/485595a3d2fb7bbc5ac2e75196e46b31

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was simply calling the `.begin()` fx present in `sessionmaker`:

```py
class MainDB:
    # create connection engine
    base_db_engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{get_project_root()}/db/base.db')

    # init tables
    Base = declarative_base()
    Base.metadata.create_all(base_db_engine)

class GenDBInterface:
    # create db session
    session: Session = sessionmaker(bind=MainDB.base_db_engine)

    def run(self):
        acc = Accounts(email='hello', password='hi', user_token='hello')
        with self.session.begin() as s:
            s.add(acc)
```

I'm not using this in a flask/FastAPI environment though. Might be different.